# How to hide div using vbscript on the basis of database condition?

Tags: vbscript

```
businessSQL = "Select orgid, organisationname, weblink, featured, logofile, shortdesc, webpage FROM directory WHERE dircatid = " & dircattouse & " AND orgtype = 1 AND delstatus <> 0 AND intapproved = 1 ORDER BY featured DESC, organisationname ASC;"
businessRS.Open businessSQL, dbconn
```

the above one is my select query and if `businessRS.("logofile")` is not empty then I want to hide my div with id= img, otherwise it is visible. How can I do this using VBScript?

I tried following code to hide the div:

```
<%
Dim oElm
oElm = businessRS("logofile")
Dim Div
Set Div = document.getElementById("img")
if oElm Is Nothing then
  Response.write("Div.style.visibility = ""hidden"" ") 
else
  Response.write("Div.style.visibility = ""visible"" ")
end if
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure from your code whether you want a fully server-side implementation or if you want to venture into client-side VBScript, but one solution could be to conditionally insert a bit of CSS to set the div's visibility:

```
<%
    ' connect, run SQL etc
    '...

    if IsNull(oElm) then 
%>
<style type="text/css">
    div#img { visibility: hidden; }
</style>
<% 
    end if 
%>
```